# Proving that the limit is greater than any $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and $t\in \mathbb R$, $A=\{x\in [b,c) \mid f(x) > t\}$  so that $\inf(A) \notin A$.
Let $M\in \mathbb R$, so that $\lim_{x\to \inf(A)}f(x)=M$.
Prove that $M\geq t$.

I showed that, since $\inf(A)\notin A$, $f(\inf(A))\leq t$.
Then I tried showing that from the definition of limit and that $\lim_{x\to \inf(A)}f(x)=M$,
it means that "around the point" $\inf(A)$, the function is $M$.
What brought me to the opposite of what I needed to prove. I got to the conclusion that:
$f(\inf(A))\leq t \Rightarrow M \leq t$

What did I get wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how you got to the opposite conclusion.  Write $a=\inf(A)$.  There is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\in A,\ x_n>a,\ x_n\to a$ by the definition of $\inf$.  Now $$f(x_n)>t,$$ since $x_n\in A$.  Taking the limit as $x\to a$ on both sides gives $$M\geq t$$.

Comment: Why when you take the limit it gives you that ≥?

Comment: The limit of the left-hand side is $M$ and the limit on the right-hand side is $t$.  When you take the limit, > changes to $\geq$.